# NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Type' has no instance getter 'imgPath'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Am Trying to access a field by the name *imgPath* that is in class *BusinessCard* 
Here's the Code

```
class BusinessCard extends StatelessWidget {


 final String imgPath;
  final String bsnName;
  final String bsnDescription;
  final String bsnLocation;
  final String bsnReview;
  get _imgPath => imgPath;
  BusinessCard(
      this.imgPath, this.bsnName, this.bsnDescription, this.bsnLocation, this.bsnReview);
...}
```

Here's Where am trying to access it from

```
class _DetailsTopPartState extends State<DetailsTopPart> {


    Color fcl = const Color(0xffff005d);
      Color lcl = const Color(0xffeb0ec6);
      Color txt = const Color(0xff042fc9);

  dynamic card = BusinessCard;

  decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(card._imgPath)
          ),}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by changing your code like this

```
dynamic card = BusinessCard;
```

to

```
dynamic card = BusinessCard();
```

In fact you are trying to get `imagePath` in `BusinessCard` which is a type not a value. You need to create an instance of this class before accessing instance variables (by calling default constructor with `ExampleClass()`or by calling static constructor like `ExampleClass.fromTest(test)`).

You can learn more [Here](https://medium.com/jay-tillu/constructors-in-dart-4f972186c372)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't give any parameter to your `BusinessCard` constructor when declaring the variable `card`. Also you named your getter `_imgPath`. In Flutter if you put an `_` in front of something it means that it is private so you don't have access to it outside from its class.